# Share video stream across users

Tags: networking, html, streaming, video-streaming

I have access to a machine with static IP. Is it possible to create a web page from which I can stream a video such that all viewers of the webpage are watching the same instance of the video? - That is, if one viewer pauses or steps video forward, it reflects on every viewer's page as well
I would also like to account for huge network speed differences (add some buffering capability)

To some extent, I'm trying to recreate the functionality of [Wavelength](http://wavelength.fm) and other similar services. The reason I'm trying to recreate is to avoid unecessary upload delays (the file I'm looking to 'broadcast' is already present on the server)

Comment: so is the machine with the static IP local or a webserver?  You won't need the static IP on the local machine.  You will need to either have a VPS or dedicated server, or an account at a streaming service (justin.tv or the like). low cost or shared hosts aren't going to let you do this kind of thing (it's a resource hog of both bandwidth and server CPU).

Comment: I have nginx on it, so I guess it could be a web server..but it is definitely not local.I actually started looking at VLC's rtp/rtsp options and from the descriptions, it might be what I'm looking for

Comment: Well point is, the server that's going to be streaming is the server that needs the static IP.  Whatever single computer is uploading to the server doesn't need a static IP (it won't hurt it just doesn't help).  The reason you can't just serve multiple user directly for the originating computer is the bandwidth.  Each receiver would need a slice of your upstream bandwidth and that is typically restricted, as well as some of your other resources.  Servers on the other hand have plenty of bandwidth to give a slice to each of your users.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the right computer has the static IP. I have a server with a relatively high upload speed (124Mbps+). This server has a static IP. I'm looking to stream a file that is present on this server to multiple clients..Since I'm looking to do this only among 3-4 clients, I think 124Mbps should be sufficient..no?

Comment: I have no idea how much bandwidth each user would take up, it would depending largely on the quality and resolution of the feed. Most often the presenters computer uploads to one server that has much faster outbound connections, it serves as the hub.  I suspect your users could get laggy, again tho depending on the resolution and quality of the feed.